# Queue works not as expected

Tags: tensorflow

In the TensorFlow Tutorial "Threading_and Queues" there is an example how using the queue (the animated gif at the beginning (see https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html).

I tried the example on my computer and it works not as expected:

```
import tensorflow as tf
q = tf.FIFOQueue(3, tf.float32)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
q_size = q.size()
init = q.enqueue_many(([0.,0.,0.],))
# for getting the number of elements in the queue
q_size.eval()
```

0

```
# enqueue three elements into the queue
init.run()
q_size.eval()
```

3

```
x = q.dequeue()
y = x + 1
q_inc = q.enqueue([y])
q_inc.run()
y.eval()
```

1

```
q_size.eval()
```

2

```
q_inc.run()
y.eval()
```

2

```
q_size.eval()
```

1

```
q_inc.run()
y.eval()
```

3

```
q_size.eval()
```

0

So the queue is empty :-(
Each time running q_inc shortens the queue. `y` is not enqueued. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dequeuing twice for each enqueue.

`q_inc.run()` triggers `y`, which triggers `x` which dequeues from queue

`y.eval()` triggers `x` which also dequeues from queue

Comment: Thanks, I did't realized that `y.eval()` also dequeued from the queue.